# App crashes when assigning array from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Inside a method, I have:

```
[self makeRequestToServerForVehicles:self.load.loadId successBlock:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    Info *info = mappingResult.array[0];

    self.load.bagOne = info.firstArray;
    self.load.bagTwo = info.secondArray;
    self.load.itemsNeeded = [self itemsFromBagTwo]; <---- App crashes here




- (NSArray *)itemsFromBagTwo{

    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Group *group in self.load.bagTwo) {
        [items addObjectsFromArray:group.items];
    }

    return items;
}
```

When I run this, the app crashes with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

When I NSLog the array that is returned, it does not come back nil. It comes back with the items that it needs to come back with.

If I do this,

```
NSArray *items = [self itemsFromBagTwo]; <--- Doesn't crash
```

I am not sure what is wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is the `itemsNeeded` property on `self.load` declared?

Comment: @jeffamaphone, itemsNeeded is also an NSArray

Comment: Could you show all attributes of the property **itemsNeeded**?

Comment: `setObjectForKey:` is not an array method. Are any of the objects you're creating an `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` ?

Comment: You're not giving us enough information. Post the entire header of the class of self, and of the object type for its `load` property.

Comment: Where is the exception stack trace?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: The problem was indeed that I had an NSDictionary object in one of my other classes which was proposed by @MikeWelsh. It was a complex solution but I appreciate everybody's help.

Answer (score 1):

The error makes it sound like the compiler is interpreting `self.load.`itemsNeeded using key value coding instead of getter and setter methods.

Try rewriting your code as

```
[[self load] setItemsNeeded: [self itemsFromBagTwo] ];
```

And see what happens. (That code does explicit method calls rather than ambiguous code that might invoke a getter and a setter, might reference items in a struct, or might compile as key-value coding.)